# Need help using EJS

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am exploring the use of the EJS templating system and am unsure of how to use it to get SQL data to be available to be rendered in a view.

In my app.js I have something like this:

```html
conn.query("select name,age from people", function(err, people, moreResultSets) {
    for (var i=0;i<people.length;i++){
        console.log(people[i].NAME, "\t\t", people[i].AGE);
    }
                                       
    conn.close(function(){
     console.log("Connection Closed");
 });
});
```

And I have the following code to route the proper view:

```html
app.get('/test1', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/test1');
})
```

My confusion lies in making the people data available from the query
statement to be rendered in the view. All of the examples I have seen
have the variables defined locally inside the app.get code block and I
am unclear how to jump from that to my situation.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!
-Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render after you have the data.

```
app.get('/test1', function (req, res) {

    conn.query("select name,age from people", function (err, people, moreResultSets) {
        res.render('pages/test1', {
            people: people
        });

        conn.close(function () {
            console.log('Connection Closed');
        });
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<% if (people) { %>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) { %>
        <div><%= people[i].name %></div>
    <% } %>
<% } else { %>
   <div>No people found</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense after seeing it... :)